# "The 'div' element wasn't closed" is caused by @using (Html.BeginForm()) in my view. I'm 100% sure I'm closing it properly

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I get this error in my view:

> the 'div' element wasn't closed

[image]
I have tried in the second way, but without success

Error caused by second way:

[image]

[minimized but still doing the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utJOk.png)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "content", @id = "transferContent" }))
           {
            <div class="container" style="margin-top:50px" id="einAusContainer">
                <h2>hello</h2>
            </div>
           }
```

Now it's showing the red ~ under the @ sign in the beginning of the code

Comment: You see the `-` icons on the left side of your editor? Minimize them one by one and you can identify which `<div>` is missing it's closing tag. The second image is just wrong syntax.

Comment: Don't show pics of code, paste it as text (formatted as code)!

Comment: regarding your update: Paste your entire view in the question. We can't solve your problem with screenshots. (If the `View` is very big, you can put it on https://pastebin.com/ and add the link in the question)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it :) It was because of incorrect comment syntax: `<!-----Eingabe----->`.
It needs only double hyphens on the both sides: `<!--Eingabe-->`. Any way, Thank you both for attention!